# Problems with javascript code not creating a cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies

The following code comes from an older html document, and works. It calls a script to create a cookie that is used by another document to display an image [imagetag] and its description [imagetext].

```
<script>
document.write("<a href='albumview-a.html'><img onclick=\"(createCookie('albumcookie','" + count[1] + "',0))\"" + imagetag[1] + " alt='' border='1' width='300'></a>");
document.write("<p class='noindent'>" + imagetext[1] + "</p>");
</script>
```

However, I would like to change is so that it only displays the description When I change the code shown below, it fails to write the cookie, and my poor brain cannot figure out why. Any ideas?

```
<script>
document.write("<a href='albumview-a.html'><onclick=\"(createCookie('albumcookie','" + count[1] + "',0))\"" + "<p class='noindent'>" + imagetext[1] + "</p></a>");
</script>
```

Comment: Because your generated HTML is completely wrong

Comment: Just compare the number of angle brackets (`>`) you have in the strings.

Comment: Thank you, mplungjan! I couldn't see the trees for the forest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your generated HTML is invalid

Check out

```js
const count = ["1","2"]
const imagetag = ["...","src=https://assets.stickpng.com/images/58afd6b70187e59a7d8a8f1c.png"]
const imagetext = ["Text 1","Text 2"]

document.write("<a href='albumview-a.html'><img onclick=\"(createCookie('albumcookie','" + count[1] + "',0))\"" + imagetag[1] + " alt='' border='1' width='300'></a>");
document.write("<p class='noindent'>" + imagetext[1] + "</p>");
```

versus

```js
const imagetext = ["Text 1","Text 2"]
const count = ["1","2"]

document.write("<p class='noindent'><a href='albumview-a.html' onclick=\"(createCookie('albumcookie','" + count[1] + "',0))\">" + imagetext[1] + "</a></p>");
```